# ASP.NET when responding with JSON, getting a <pre> tag

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, json

EDIT 2: Some response I found mention modifying the 'datatype', is that a header? i did try modifying the `Content-Type` to `application/json` which didn't help.

EDIT: I am still having this issue, just to add to this information I am sending a file as input, here are the HTTP headers that i am sending, I know the 'Accept' header is not an issue since I have another request that is not causing any isses:

`Host: localhost:26479 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0 Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8 Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate Referer: http://localhost:26479/Home/FileUploadBrowser Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------41184676334 Content-Length: 1104`

I have the following controller method ( still a work in progress):

```
Function uploadFileToAmazon(ByVal key As String) As ActionResult
        Dim incomingStream As Stream = Me.Request.InputStream
        Dim bucketName As String = ""
        Dim accessKey As String = ""
        Dim secretKey As String = ""
        ConnectToAmazon(bucketName, accessKey, secretKey)
        Dim client As AmazonS3 = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(accessKey, secretKey, RegionEndpoint.USEast1)
        Dim titledRequest As PutObjectRequest
        titledRequest = New PutObjectRequest

        With titledRequest
            .WithBucketName(bucketName)
            .WithKey(key)
            .WithInputStream(incomingStream)
        End With
        Dim response As S3Response = client.PutObject(titledRequest)
        Return Json(New With {Key .success = "true", Key .msg = "uploaded"})
    End Function
```

Original question: 
Here is the problem that I'm having, for some reason it is sending the following message to the front end after completing `<pre>{"success":"true","msg":"uploaded"}</pre>`. I am confused, where is this `<pre>` tag is coming from and how to I get rid of it? Thank you

Comment: Is the `datatype` set to json in your ajax upload?

Comment: I'm not sure, here are what my headers look like: `Host: localhost:26479
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://localhost:26479/Home/FileUploadBrowser
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------41184676334
Content-Length: 1104
`

Comment: Maybe this is causing the behaviour: `Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8` since it is instructing the server to prefer HTML content and (wild guess here) maybe VB is encapsulating in a <pre> tag? Do you have any control on the client side of this to see how the request is created?

Comment: Is the pre tag returned on the wire or you are seing it in some other way?

Comment: I can see the tag in the firebug console. (not sure what you mean by 'on the wire')